# How can I update a Tkinter canvas in the middle of a function call?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing Conway's game of life using Tkinter, and I want to have a "Go" button which allows the animation to begin, and continue stepping automatically until terminated. I'm using a Canvas to draw the environment, but since the "Go" button needs to complete the function call before it updates the canvas, the window just hangs until I kill the process. I've attempted to use `canvas.update_idletasks()` and `canvas.update()` (followed by a few seconds of sleeping) at points where I want to updated the canvas but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Any Ideas? Below is my GameOfLife class, the Environment class just manages the "board" of cells.

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import *
from time import time
from Environment import *

class GameOfLife(object):
    def __init__(self, master, envDim):
        self.unitSize = 10
        self.dimension = envDim * self.unitSize
        self.environment = Environment(envDim)
        self.environment.seedBoard()
        self.started = False

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        Button(frame, text = "Go", command = self.go_call).pack(side = LEFT)
        Button(frame, text = "Clear", command = self.reset_call).pack(side = LEFT)
        Button(frame, text = "Close", command = frame.quit).pack(side = RIGHT)
        canvas = self.drawCanvas(master, self.dimension)

def drawCanvas(self, master, dimension):
    self.canvas = Canvas(master, width = self.dimension, height = self.dimension)
    self.canvas.pack()
    return self.canvas

def go_call(self):
    print "<< Go Call >>"
    if self.environment.started == False:
        self.environment.seedBoard()

    self.drawState(self.environment)
    self.environment.nextBoard()
    self.started = True
    while True:
        self.environment.nextBoard()
        self.canvas.delete(ALL)
        self.drawState(self.environment)
        self.canvas.update_idletasks()
        sleep(4)

def reset_call(self):
    print "<< Reset Call >>"
    self.canvas.delete(ALL)
    self.environment = Environment(self.environment.dim)

def drawState(self, environment):
    size = self.unitSize
    for x in range(environment.dim):
        for y in range(environment.dim):
            if environment.matrix[x][y].alive == True:
                xs = x * size
                ys = y * size
                self.canvas.create_rectangle(xs, ys, xs+size, ys+size, fill = 'black')

envDim = 70
root = Tk()
gol = GameOfLife(root, envDim)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Minor suggestion. It appears that you're deleting all the canvas objects and creating new ones each time the state is updated. It might be more efficient to keep the same rectangles on the canvas and just change their fill color at each iteration.

Comment: Why `sleep` for 4 seconds, isn't that much ?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but it's really a bad idea to do imports like you do in the example code -- unless you know exactly what each module exports you could easily have name clashes. As a rule of thumb you should never do `import *`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should never put an infinite loop inside your GUI program, and you definitely should never, ever call sleep.  You already have an infinite loop running -- the event loop -- so take advantage of it.

The way to do animations like this is to write a function that draws one frame of the animation (or turn of the game, pick your metaphor). Then, have that function call itself via `after`.

Roughly speaking your code should look like this:

```
def draw(self):
    # draw the board according to the current state
    ...
    # arrange for the next frame to draw in 4 seconds
    self.after(4000, self.draw)

def __init__(self, ...):
    ...
    self.go = tk.Button(self, text="Go", command=self.draw)
    ...
```

If you want to add a stop button, all it needs to do is set a flag. Then, in `draw`, simply check for the flag before calling `self.after`