# Tkinter need to update canvas mid process. It only updates when finished

Tags: python, tkinter

i can see i have a similar problem to [How can I update a Tkinter canvas in the middle of a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964721/how-can-i-update-a-tkinter-canvas-in-the-middle-of-a-function-call) but i cant translate the accepted answer to my situation. In that SO answer, the solution of a function that calls itself is fine in principle, but i need to pass a list `a` into the function, not just call it.

btw, yep i know the program works : printing the list `a` which is the 1st line #'d out in `def renderGUI(a):` works just fine

QUESTION : how do i get Tkinter to animate the list `a` (0 is light is off) into ons and offs?

please note i've also tried `w.update_idletasks()` too, though some peeps seem to be pretty down on this approach.

the code is below

MANY thanks in advance:

```
from sys import stdout
from Tkinter import *
from time import sleep

numLights = 30
a     = [0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
speed = [0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

# now set the speeds
for i in range (0,numLights):
    #print "i: " + str(i)
    if a[i] > 0:
        speed[i] = a[i]

# speed[n] is the speed that the nth light will travel at.  the bigger the number the slower: its the number of passes it dwells on each light

master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=1000, height=100)
master.title("Speedlights")
w.pack()

size = 8
space = 12
offsetL = 10
offsetD = 35

for i in range (1,numLights):
    w.create_oval((i*space)+offsetL,offsetD,(i*space)+size+offsetL,offsetD+size)

def renderGUI(a):
    #print a
    for k in range (0,numLights):
        if a[k]>0:
            #then it must be 'on' #tg='L'+str(i)
            w.create_oval((k*space)+offsetL,offsetD,(k*space)+size+offsetL,offsetD+size, fill="red")#, tags=(tg))
        else:
            #turn it off
            w.create_oval((k*space)+offsetL,offsetD,(k*space)+size+offsetL,offsetD+size, fill="grey")#, tags=(tg))

# set this up as a function?
for i in range (0,numLights):
    master.after(100, renderGUI(a))
    w.update_idletasks()    
    for n in range(0,numLights):
        if a[n]>1:
            a[n] = a[n]-1
        elif a[n] == 1:
                #then its about to become nought, right?
                a[n-1] = speed[n]
                speed[n-1] = speed[n]
                a[n] = a[n]-1
                continue
        continue

btn = Button(master, text='Stop', width=20, command=master.destroy)
btn.pack()
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would be happy to help, but I don't really understand what you want to achieve with the led lights. A simple question, first: why don't you put the 'for' loop in a function, and this function to run with 'after' ? Like you propose in your comment in the code. Then you can left 'renderGUI' as a normal call ; I don't see what difference it makes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your program work, just but your `for` loop inside a function and call it via `after`:

```
def f():
    for i in range (0,numLights):
        master.after(100, renderGUI(a))
        w.update_idletasks()    
        for n in range(0,numLights):
            if a[n]>1:
                a[n] = a[n]-1
            elif a[n] == 1:
                    #then its about to become nought, right?
                    a[n-1] = speed[n]
                    speed[n-1] = speed[n]
                    a[n] = a[n]-1
                    continue
            continue

btn = Button(master, text='Stop', width=20, command=master.destroy)
btn.pack()
master.after(1, f)
master.mainloop()
```

---

However, if you want to get rid of `update_idletasks`, you could use a coroutine (wrapped into a decorator here):

```
def updatesdisplay(root, t=0):
    def _updatesdisplay(func):
        def driver(iterator):
            try: next(iterator)
            except StopIteration: pass
            else: 
                if t: root.after(t, driver, iterator)
                else: root.after_idle(driver, iterator)
        def wrapped():
            driver(func())
        return wrapped
    return _updatesdisplay

@updatesdisplay(master, 100) # 100 because we want to slow things down a bit
def f():
    for i in range (0,numLights):
        renderGUI(a)
        yield # window gets updated here
        for n in range(0,numLights):
            if a[n]>1:
                a[n] = a[n]-1
            elif a[n] == 1:
                    #then its about to become nought, right?
                    a[n-1] = speed[n]
                    speed[n-1] = speed[n]
                    a[n] = a[n]-1
                    continue
            continue

btn = Button(master, text='Stop', width=20, command=master.destroy)
btn.pack()
master.after(1, f)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Dominc, thanks.you are legend! Question, though... WHY would i want to get rid of idletasks? it seems pythonic to leave it simpler than adding a coroutine

Comment: related Q, when the graphics are Tkinter-ing along, the mouse cursor shows as busy. shouldn't it be an arrow, so i can click 'stop' button?